# How to get rid of empty <pre> block in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the pre tag right now to format JSON's I'm displaying. However, I want to hide the block when I'm not using it. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like basic CSS and JS. Add an ID or Class to the `<pre>` and use your function that populates it to show the `<pre>`. If you have an empty function, it would hide the `<pre>` with something like `display: none;` in CSS